# Google Api Route Without Steps

Tags: google-maps

One question for google api route

I wanted to know if it is possible to make a request to the google just getting the timing and duration of the full path without receiving each of the intermediate steps

thanks

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

 "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 45.51014580,
               "lng" : -73.55252489999999
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 43.65331030,
               "lng" : -79.38373319999999
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Datos de mapa ©2013 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "542 km",
                  "value" : 542385
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5h 14 min",
                  "value" : 18834
               },
               "end_address" : "Montreal, Quebec, Canadá",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 45.50857120,
                  "lng" : -73.55376740
               },
               "start_address" : "Toronto, Ontario, Canadá",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 43.65331030,
                  "lng" : -79.38276750
               },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DistanceMatrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

> The Google Distance Matrix API is a service that provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and 
>   destinations. The information returned is based on the recommended route between start and end points, as calculated 
>   by the Google Maps API, and consists of rows containing duration and distance values for each pair.

Answer (score 0):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Toronto&destinations=Montreal&sensor=false

(Note the parameters: origins and destinations (plural form, unlike the directions api)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Montreal, QC, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Toronto, ON, Canada" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "542 km",
                  "value" : 542384
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 hours 14 mins",
                  "value" : 18835
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```